# Praat will not recognize regular expressions

Tags: praat

I'm having an issue with a Praat script. I would like to define the labels I want to define the label I want to look for with a regular expression like this:

```
if label$ = "[AEIOU].."
```

However, Praat chokes on this, it never applies the conditional to the appropriate regex (which I got from [Praat's own help site](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Regular_expressions_1__Special_characters.html)). I have tried with single quotes, double quotes, and no quotes, all the same. It will do the conditional if I put a an actual vowel name in, like "EH1".

Is there some magic trick to get Praat to recognize its own documented regex, or is it broken? If it's broken, do I just have to put in every ARPABET vowel in a list?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Praat, but `if a = b` is hard to interpret in any other way than looking for equivalence between two scalars. I'm guessing you need something like `if index_regex(label$, "[AEIOU]..") > 0` based on very quick googling.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the info. Rammed my head against this wall for a long time.